# Damages to LED from accumulated snow?

Tags: lighting, fenders, snow

On my bike the rear light is a LED integrated in the fender. The gap between the LED group and the tire is quite narrow. The make is the same as in the picture below.

[image]

From the last time I cycled onto snow (with a different bike), I remember that quite some dirty ice can accumulate between the fender and the tire.

Can the accumulated dirty ice permanently damage the integrated LED?

Comment: The bigger danger is that the rubbing between the tire and an accumulation of ice causes physical damage.

Comment: I cannot  see  how this can be answered without knowing the brand/model and quality  of the fender/led assembly.  While I would expect a led based fender light to be protected against water, I would not be so certain with an eBay $2 special.

Answer (score 2):

The LED group needs to be waterproof anyways, and it needs to withstand dirt that's thrown at it from the tire at quite some speed. **Snow won't penetrate any further than water**. Also, since the fender looks very plastic to me, it won't be attacked by the salt that your city may have used to clear the roads.

**As such, I believe that your LED should be perfectly safe and won't be killed by any amount of snow that you choose to bike through.**

---

Cables may be a different matter as blocks of snow can tear at them in ways that water can't. But as long as the cable to your rear light runs straight up in the middle of the fender, that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Most dynamo lights I've seen *aren't* fully sealed.  They normally have drain holes in the bottom to let water out.  I lost a B&M Secula to water ingress from underneath, from example (strangely, it only killed the standlight drive cirvuit).  However the tyre throws water at  the inside of the mudguard so this side should be well protected against water and therefore snow

Comment: @ChrisH Perfectly true :-) Note that I said "snow won't penetrate *any further* than water". No matter how well protected a light is, if I either throw water or snow at it from the same direction with the same speed, I always expect the water to be more dangerous than the snow. And as long as the light is protected from water thrown at it from one specific direction, I also expect that same light to be protected from snow thrown at it from that same direction.

Comment: Sure, I was more responding to "waterproof", which I guess you meant in the sense of "sufficiently waterproof" though I read it as meaning completely sealed

Comment: ***Snow won't penetrate any further than water*** Where'd you grow up?  You've apparently never gotten whacked upside the head with a snowball and had to dig ice pellets out of your ear.  ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Oh, I know snow balls all too well, especially the ones that were shoved into my neck or wiped across my face (kids, don't do this, it hurts brutally, no kid deserves that!). But I guess, you'd also get quite a bit of water in your ear when you were hit by a water ball at the same speed from the same direction as your snowball, no? You might even get some water into your middle ear...

Comment: "Snow won't penetrate any further than water" Since snow is made of ice, when packed and pressed (for example when jammed between a tire and fender) it can mechanically damage e.g. plastic and create an opening; water won't do this unless it's under high pressure.

Comment: @Armand Do you have experience with that? The way I see it is that the tire is moving parallel to the fender, and thus not able to put any significant pressure on the snow that might accumulate under the fender. When the tire comes into contact with the snow buildup, it will tend to rub the top layer away, or melt it partially, allowing a thin ice layer to form between the snow and the tire. It may become more dangerous when a piece of compacted snow buildup breaks away from the fender and is pushed forward by the tire. That's why I mentioned that cables are somewhat more at risk.

Comment: @cmaster I've got mostly experience with car tires and fenders, but the bike fenders tend to be much flimsier so I think both have problems. Let's remember that in snow we are likely riding bike tires with deep treads and/or metal studs, which will grip the snow/ice mixture. There are also likely to be "reinforcing materials" like rocks and twigs and leaves that build the strength of the ice/snow mass.  If the light's back is totally flush with the inside of the fender, you're probably OK, but if there's any unevenness like a lip I think there could be an issue.  Personally I would try it out.

Comment: @Armand Well, yes, I didn't think about studs, but they are largely irrelevant: The snow buildup will simply have depressions where the studs are moving beneath. Also, you are perfectly right that the robustness of modern bike fenders is typically just a joke. They are just very thin strips of plastic. And judging by the image in the question, I'd wager that the light enclosure is the strongest, most robust part of the entire fender. If the tire really managed to push a block of ice under the fender, the entire construction would simply move up and out of the way (possibly breaking the fender)